# Can someone reduce these 3 constructors to a single one?

Tags: c++

I tried to write a short class to create a binary-tree and i'm not happy with these 3 separate constructors, but i cant figure out how to pack the code into a single one. Can somebody help?

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class node{
private:
    std::string label;
    std::shared_ptr<node> left;
    std::shared_ptr<node> right;
public:
    node(const std::string& name) : label(name), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    node(const std::string& name, const node& leftChild) : 
            label(name), 
            left(std::make_shared<node>(leftChild)), 
            right(nullptr) {}
    node(const std::string& name, const node& leftChild, const node& rightChild) : 
        label(name), 
        left(std::make_shared<node>(leftChild)), 
        right(std::make_shared<node>(rightChild)) {}
};

int main()
{
    //          "root"
    //         /     \ 
    //    "left"    "right"
    //      /
    // "left.left"
    auto root = std::make_shared<node>("root", node("left", node("left.left")), node("right"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about passing shared pointers to ctor: `node(const std::string& name, std::shared_ptr<node> leftChild = {}, std::shared_ptr<node> rightChild = {})`

Comment: Side note: There doesn't appear to be a need for multiple `node` owners, so  you might be able to use `std::unique_ptr` instead of the much heavier-weight `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: What's wrong with 3 constructors?

Comment: @SergeyA they feel kind of redundant :D

Comment: @user3365922 because im limited to this exact initialization you can see in main

Comment: You actually need a dozen more - accepting rvalue references.

Comment: Why are the members shared_ptr? Looks like they should be unique_ptr, indicating sole ownership.

Comment: You can pass `optional<Node>` arguments and default them to `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `std::optional`:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class node{
private:
    std::string label;
    std::shared_ptr<node> left;
    std::shared_ptr<node> right;
public:
    node(const std::string& name,
         const std::optional<node>& leftChild = {},
         const std::optional<node>& rightChild = {}) : 
        label(name), 
        left(leftChild ? std::make_shared<node>(*leftChild) : nullptr), 
        right(rightChild ? std::make_shared<node>(*rightChild) : nullptr) {}
};

int main()
{
    //          "root"
    //         /     \ 
    //    "left"    "right"
    //      /
    // "left.left"
    auto root = std::make_shared<node>("root", node("left", node("left.left")), node("right"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be unfamiliar with *forwarding constructors*

```
class node{
private:
    std::string label;
    std::shared_ptr<node> left;
    std::shared_ptr<node> right;
public:
    node(const std::string& name)
        : label(name) {}
    node(const std::string& name, const node& leftChild) 
        : node(name) 
        , left(std::make_shared<node>(leftChild)) {}
    node(const std::string& name, const node& leftChild, const node& rightChild)
        : node(name, left)
        , right(std::make_shared<node>(rightChild)) {}
};
```

So technically you still have three constructors, but there's no duplicate code anymore.